# Smooth colorFill - FloodFill in as3

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a problem like the problem below. I'm using a floodFill on a BitmapData.

But with images with a border not "clear" (like the images with a soft border on Fireworks) the floodFill isn't really good. (look at the picture)

http://www.mediafire.com/view/?8q3kyv95ccd3693

I can make the floodFill more "smooth"?

I do not have sufficient privileges to post the picture up so let sympathy for that and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12836730/actionscript-3-0-transparent-image-floodfill

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not tested this class myself, but it looks like the floodFill method does what you ask (it takes a "tolerance" argument, which the native floodFill method doesn't):

Link to fla file: http://hangunsworld.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2007/10/floodfill.fla

Comment: Link is not available. Can You please give reupload or give any other link